# How to update Cognito Token in AWS API Gateway Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using developer authenticated identities to authenticate the uses via Cognito to access API Gateway.

The login works, and I am able to generate the token for the user from back-end.

When I use JS SDK, it refreshes the token automatically. The user logs in, and SDK handles the token expiration.

But with Android SDK, this doesn't seem to be the case. Do I have to do something to get updated token whenever it expires?

Comment: Are you using Identity Pool or User Pool? There is a lot of discussion here on the Cognito Android SDK https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225622

Comment: we are using identity pool @Jack Kohn